# Connect TouchMove to MouseMove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this awesome script that creates a magnifying glass affect on mouse over, and I'm having a really hard time making it work on mobile.

The script on its own seems to somewhat work on mobile but only on tap. I found another piece of javascript which creates a simulated mouse event and it actually works surprisingly well on mobile.

The only issue is that once you touch and hold the image on your phone, it never seems to "let go" and navigating anything else on the site no longer works. I've created a codepen with what I've got so far:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWaQBz

```
Does SO really want me to paste hundreds of lines of code?
```

I'm very new to writing Javascript, so forgive me if you see something really stupid.

Comment: SO doesn't want you to paste loads of code, but just the most relevant part :)

Comment: It actually depends on how you could illustrate your issue, if you can some how describe your issue without writing a code, then I'm sure that shouldn't be a problem. But the chances of that happening is pretty rare, I don't think it could be a considered a programming question then :) IMHO.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/jquerymobile_events_touch.asp This link will highlight the events. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp This link shows other touch events. Use them wisely. Although why would you want this on a phone? It's FAR easier to just zoom in on touch screens. I wouldn't bother with this on mobile devices. Also, what's your other piece of js that creates simulated mouse events? I'm currently building a library for custom mouse events. That might be useful!

Comment: Also, if this is your only code, then I would also suggest not using jquery and just access the DOM in simpler ways. It's not worth the additional 90kb for saving just a couple of lines.